# Hashlocation strategy in angular on top of ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular-cli

I'm currently building a feature angular application on top of an asp.net application. I want the angular module to load on all pages but not interfering with the routing of the asp.net application.

I achieve this by using hashlocation strategy but the problem is that some modules are not found when navigating in the application. The bundels are placed in a folder called "plugins"

For instance

> localhost:/foo1 - WORKS
>
> localhost:/foo1/foo2 - One module not found (looks in foo2/plugins folder)
>
> localhost:/foo1/foo2/foo3 - Custom themes not found and module not found (looks in foo2/foo3/plugins)

Is there a way to set the deploy url in angular cli to a relative base folder as to look for files in /plugins disregarding the current url?

Answer (score 0):

Is Static files are allowed in your .net app ?
For example in .net core, be default static files allowed and all files from wwwroot folder you can use in ur application.

Comment: I don't really know. I have not built the .net app and have basically no control over it. It is not core though. The problem is that the angular script searches for the files in the wrong folder based on the url of the .net app instead of i'ts own folder.